# Is this the best way for subclass in python

Tags: python, class

I have I timer where I want to increase and decrease the timer based on addition and subtraction operations.

So, I have came to this solution to a subclass of int for non-negative numbers. Is this a correct way to do the subclass work? For me looks awkward the 'return Positive(self.value)'.

```
class Positivo(int):
    def __new__(self, value: int =0):
        self.value = value
        return int.__new__(Positivo, self.value)

    def __sub__(self, op_value):
        if self.value < op_value:
            self.value = 0
        else:
            self.value -= op_value
        return Positivo(self.value)

    def __add__(self, op_value):
        self.value += op_value
        return Positivo(self.value)
```

EDIT1:
The alternative with 'self':

```
class Positivo(int):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self = int.__new__(Positivo, value)

    def __sub__(self, op_value):
        return Positivo(super().__sub__(op_value) if op_value <= self else 0)

    def __add__(self, op_value):
        return Positivo(super().__add__(op_value))
```

Comment: Probably the best thing is not to subclass `int` at all.

Comment: In any case, if you *are* going to do this, then `return Positive(something)` is the *right* way to do it, otherwise you are retunring a regular `int` object. But note, `__sub__` and `__add__` shouldn't mutate the object, and indeed, there is no point in having a `self.value` , and perhaps even **more** importantly, `self` in `__new__` is **not the instance** and shouldn't be called `self`. It is *the class*, so you are assigning a *class variable* not an instance variable. Which is almost certainly not what you intended (and, shouldn't probably be there in the first place)

Comment: Use `__init__` instead of `__new__`, you don't need `__new__` at all here.

Comment: The underlying `int` class has a value, set by `__new__()`, that is entirely unrelated to `self.value`.  Any time you modify `self.value`, you put the object in a schizophrenic state, where your methods are using the new `self.value`, and inherited `int` methods are using the immutable underlying value.  Subclassing `int` is a workable approach, but the objects have to be immutable for consistency, and you should be using the underlying value (which is simply `self`) instead of an attribute you created.

Comment: At the very least, your class doesn't enforce the implied constraint. `Positive(-5)` creates a value representing a negative integer. All you are doing is preventing *subtraction* from producing a negative value. Also, you really seem to be representing *non-negative* numbers, not positive numbers, since subtraction can still produce 0.

Comment: (I am a bit concerned by the general feeling from these comments, and more so by the suggestions to close the question. While the comments are technically correct, this is obvious code being used to play around and understand the language - the playful nature of this kind of snippet have to be taken in context)

Comment: Your last comment explains the context where you'd be using this: IMO it won't be a good place to take advantage of Python's operator overriding capabilities. Just add an explicit checking expression in the place you make the adjusts in your timer value as in `self.target = min(self.target - other_value, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer*: the answer gives general hints of what is going wrong, and how to improve your code, and learn with it. A modified `int` class that will break a *lot* of mathematical basic properties of integers **should not** be used in production code. I am assuming this is a toy.

If you need a "non-negative" class of numbers for a real situation, at least make it raise `ValueError` on any operation that would yield an invalid value, instead of silently changing the operation value to 0.

---

Yes, if you subclass one of the built-in types and want the operators to work correctly, you have to explicitly return an instance of your subclass on each of the special methods.

So, what you are doing is the way to go. If you want to "look smart", it would be possible to run a for-loop on the body of the class itself, that would automatically apply a wrapper on each of the relevant methods of "int" - but that, despite using less lines of code and avoiding copy/paste of methods, may not be the best for readability and maintainability, depending on your project.

That said, there are other important points in your code, already pointed in the comments - one of the most important is that the `__new__` method must be correct, and annotating `value` in the instance is redundant. Besides, there is only a `self` *after* you call `int.__new__`, before that there is no instance at all where you can anotate anything. The first parameter to `__new__` is the class itself, regardless of how you name it.  Anyway, if you are not modfying the value when the instance is created, there is no need to modify `__new__` at all.

The comparisons using `self.value` in the methods can be made against `self` itself: it *is* an int, after all:  `if self < op_value`, instead of `self.value`.

And also, you might want to add a `__slots__=()` to your int subclass to keep it lean: otherwise you have a whole new `dict` instance for each of your special ints.

Another thing: `int` is an immutable object type, and unless you are playing around to create a "mutable int subclass", you should never modify its state once it is created. I am again talking of assigning to "self.value". AND, of course,even if it WAS mutable, `__sub__`, `__add__` never mutate the object they are operating with: they always will return new instances. It is the "i" prefixed operators that should operate "inplace" and modify `self` if it is mutable (`__iadd__`, `__isub__`, ...).

Yet another note concerning the Python language, and unrelated to subclassing int, are type annotations. You have to keep in mind that they are an optional thing, and most of the times, if used naively, they will restrict your code more than it needs to be restricted.
Your line `def __new__(self, value: int =0):` restricts the value parameter to create an instance of the class to an int, but Python's `int` accepts a *lot* more than that. And also, there is an optional `base` parameter you are simply letting out.

Now, for a somewhat "serious" version of this, sice all operators should create a new instance, you can check the values in `__new__` alone, and just wrap the operator methods to return a new instance of it:

```
from functools import wraps

class Positivo(int):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, value, /, base=10):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            self = super().__new__(cls, value, base)
        else:
            self = super().__new__(cls, value)
        if self < 0:
            self = super().__new__(cls, 0)
            # It would be safer:
            # raise ValueError(f"Positivo out of domain value for Positivo: {self}")
        return self

    def _decorate_op(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args):
            result = getattr(super(), method)(*args)
            if isinstance(result, int):
                return Positivo(result)
            return result
        wrapper.__name__ = method
        return wrapper

    num_methods = "__add__ __sub__ __truediv__ __mul__ __pow__ __neg__ __pos__ __floor__ __floordiv__ __ceil__ __trunc__ __abs__"
 
    # dynamically creates the mathematical methods that would result in an "int":
    for method in num_methods.split():
        locals()[method] = _decorate_op(method)

    # optional: remove tooling used when creating the class body
    #so that it does not show up in the final class:
    del num_methods, _decorate_op
```

Comment: yes, because as `int` is not modifable in place there is no `__isub__`, and `-=` will just call `__sub__` again. Inside your methods, when you need the original int subtraction, use `super().__sub__(op)` <- that will call `int.__sub__` with `self` boudn to the first parametrer. : `return Positivo(super().__sub__(op) if op <= self else 0)` can be the body of your `__sub__` method.

Comment: I am sorry, but the 'for-loop' is outside of a method?

Comment: yes - it is executed when the class body is executed and _creates_ the methods, assigning then to the class-body namespace, using `locals()`

Comment: there - I added some comments.

Comment: `del method`, `value = super().__new__(cls, value, base)` & `max(0, value)`